# Can't install yarn version 1.22

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

So I had yarn 1.22 installed and wanted to check out yarn 3, installed it and decided to go back to yarn 1.22 but now every time I call `npm i -g yarn@1.22.19`, yarn 3.5.1 gets installed

I tried installing it trough the wizard, npm, and corepack.

Answer (score 0):

close the Terminal and open again ;)